# What is the proper input dimension for torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I am training a binary classifier and using `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` as the loss function. I am confused about the proper input dimension for the loss function. Should it be [n, 1] or [n, 2]? In the case of [n, 1], where n is the number of samples, the values for the targets would just be 0 or 1, which represents the class that the sample belongs to. In the case of [n, 2], the targets would be `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(targets, num_classes=2).float()`. Which one is the proper dimension and what would be the corresponding logits and/or last layer of my network?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) tells you all you need to know.

For a prediction tensor `x` of shape `(num_samples, num_classes)`, the target tensor `y` should of the exact same shape.

###### Case 1

If your number of classes is two, and they are mutually exclusive, a`x` of shape `(num_samples,)` should be contrasted with a `y` of shape `(num_samples,)` taking values `0 | 1` (but typecast to float).

###### Case 2

If your number of classes is two, but they are not mutually exclusive (multi-class classification), `x` and `y` should be of shape `(num_samples, 2)` with `y` still taking float values from `0 | 1`.

In either case, you need a final layer that projects your network's dimensionality to your number of classes (whatever that means in your context). So in case 1, something like `Linear(model_dim, 1)`, whereas in case 2 `Linear(model_dim, 2)`.

Remember **not** to apply any activation function to your network's output, as this is incorporated in `BCEWithLogitsLoss` already.

If your target labels are not discrete, adjust accordingly (values from [0..1] rather than 0 | 1).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Case 1 applies here. Since the last layer of Resnet output features with dimension 2, should I just append Linear(2, 1) after it or simply replace the num_features of the existing layer with 1?

Comment: I have no idea what these 2 features are supposed to be. I think general practice is to plug in your own full-connected layer on top of resnet.